# JSON Array serialized to XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, json

I have a JSON document that looks like this:

```
{ 
   "items": [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]
}
```

When the standard XML_SERIALIZER serializes this to XML it looks like this:

```
<root>
  <items>
   <item>one</item>
   <item>two</item>
   <item>three</item>
  </items>
</root>
```

I would like to serialize this into the following XML format:

```
<root>
  <items>
   <item>
    <value>one<value>
   </item>
   <item>
    <value>two<value>
   </item>
   <item>
    <value>three<value>
   </item>
  </items>
</root>
```

Can anyone here help with this?

My current XML_SERIALIZER options look like this:

```
XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_XML_DECL_ENABLED => false,
XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_MODE => XML_SERIALIZER_MODE_SIMPLEXML,
XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_INDENT => "    ",
XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_LINEBREAKS => "\n",
XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_ROOT_NAME => "root",
XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_DEFAULT_TAG => "item"
```

Comment: PS: I don't have control over the JSON format :(

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
{"items":[{"value":"one"},{"value":"two"}]}
```

Comment: sorry, I should have been more clear :/ 
I don't have control over the JSON, it is created by a system automatically. Thanks for the suggestion though.